# Can't create GCP Cloud Shell custom image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to create a custom Cloud Shell image, as the defaul shell includes Terraform 0.12.9 and we are still on 0.11.14

I am following these instructions https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/gcp-devops-tricks-create-a-custom-cloud-shell-image-that-includes-terraform-and-helm using CLI

I created a Dockerfile with the version of Terraform I need.

Upon running `docker build` I get the follwing error message:

```
write /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.reflection.primitives/4.0.1/system.reflection.primitives.4.0.1.nupkg: no space left on device
```

Any ideas how to overcome?

For clarity I'm  pasting the output of 'd -f'

[d -f output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2t5n.png)

Comment: Where are you building the image at? You have run out of disk space.

Comment: On the Cloud shell instance - the one with pre-provisioned preemprable VM with 5GB storage

Comment: Try building on your desktop where you have more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building a custom image, use the [environment customization script](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization) that installs the packages you need on Cloud Shell startup.

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example for downgrading Terraform version:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
TERRAFORM_VERSION="0.11.14"
curl https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip > terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
unzip -o terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
```

Put this in `~/.customize_environment` and don't forget to make that executable: `chmod 755 ~/.customize_environment`.

Comment: Will it work also with downgrading the package that is already installed to previous version?

Comment: @zuzathebomb Sure, I don't see why not.  Updated answer with an example.